# Trying to make reindex via CLI

Tags: magento2, error, reindex, cli

Hello i'm trying to do a reindex via CLI but I got this error: http://prntscr.com/kon1op

Comment: I think reindex has done but updated data not adding in cache because of file read and write issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot its a permission issue:

run the below command under your magento root(**/var/www/html/**) to fix it:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chmod 777 -R var/cache
```

Then run indexer:reindex.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

It's permission issue. First set permission using `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/yourproject/var/cache`.Hope it works.